# Input type number with "+" and decimal point

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple input:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

I would suspect/want all of these input values to successfully have these outputs:

```
2.00    => 2.00
2,00    => 2.00
+2,00   => 2.00
```

But the value of "+2.00" fails.

```
+2.00   => ""
```

I want to know why that happens. Javascript itself recognizes "+2.00" as a number.

Comment: What do you mean it fails? You can enter `+2.00`: https://jsfiddle.net/jxy4Lvdf/

Answer (score 2):

There should be no problem, not with the code you've provided. I've created the example below, where you can enter "+2.00" and hit the button to see its result.

My findings:

- ✓ Chrome 60:

  ```
  {
    "nr": "2.00",
    "type": "string",
    "directAdd": "2.001",
    "parseThenAdd": 3
  }
  ```
- ✗ Firefox 54:

  ```
  {
    "nr": "",
    "type": "string",
    "directAdd": "1",
    "parseThenAdd": NaN
  }
  ```
- ✗ Safari 9.1:

  ```
  {
    "nr": "",
    "type": "string",
    "directAdd": "1",
    "parseThenAdd": NaN
  }
  ```
- ✓ IE Edge 40 / EdgeHTML 15:

  ```
  {
    "nr": "+2.00",
    "type": "string",
    "directAdd": "+2.001",
    "parseThenAdd": 3
  }
  ```
- ✓ IE 11:

  ```
  {
    "nr": "+2.00",
    "type": "string",
    "directAdd": "+2.001",
    "parseThenAdd": 3
  }
  ```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
     var nr = document.getElementById("nr").value;
        console.log({
           nr: nr,
           type: typeof nr,
           directAdd: nr + 1.00,
           parseThenAdd: parseInt(nr, 10) + 1.00
        });
    });
  });
```

```html
<p>Try inputting "+2.00", just works.</p>
<input id="nr" step="0.01" type="number">
<button id="btn">ConsoleLogIt!</button>
```

As far as I can tell it *should* work, because as per [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)) which links to [the rules for parsing the value](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#rules-for-parsing-floating-point-number-values) which includes:

> 8. If the character indicated by position is a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-):
>
>    1. Change value and divisor to −1.
>    2. Advance position to the next character.
>    3. If position is past the end of input, return an error.
>
>    Otherwise, if the character indicated by position (the first character) is a "+" (U+002B) character:
>
>    1. Advance position to the next character. (The "+" is ignored, but it is not conforming.)
>    2. If position is past the end of input, return an error.

So as far as I can tell Firefox is wrong not to parse the "+2.00" value. Given that [I could not find a bug yet](https://www.google.nl/search?q=site%3Abugzilla.mozilla.org+input+type+number+plus+sign) I've gone ahead and [posted it to Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1392068) so we can see what the *real* experts have to say about this :-)

Comment: I get a empty value which means "" when I enter +2.00. I have set the html language to english but didn't works

Comment: In my snippet too (and if yes: what browser)? Or just in your own app (if so: try to add an [mcve] to your question)?

Comment: I went ahead and tested with various browsers. Most likely you were using Firefox that does exhibit the behavior you mentioned. (Be sure to add such detail to your question, especially if commenters indicate they cannot reproduce it.)

Comment: Thx for the edit @BenM. I must say the outcome surprised me, I would've expected it to be similar to Chrome, not Firefox.

Comment: No problem. I was also very surprised to be honest!